# Regex not working for IE but works for other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, internet-explorer

```
(function($){
    $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function(){
    };
    $.validationEngineLanguage = {
        newLang: function(){
            $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {
                "required": { // Add your regex rules here, you can take telephone as an example
                    "regex": "none",
                    "alertText": "This field is required",
                    "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "Please select an option",
                    "alertTextCheckboxe": "This checkbox is required",
                    "alertTextDateRange": "Both date range fields are required"
                },

                "phone": {
                    // credit: jquery.h5validate.js / orefalo
                    "regex": /^([\+][0-9]{1,3}[\ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9\ \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[\ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/,
                    "alertText": "Invalid phone number"
                },
                "email": {
                    // HTML5 compatible email regex ( http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#    e-mail-state-%28type=email%29 )
                    "regex": /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                    "alertText": "Invalid email address"
                },
                "integer": {
                    "regex": /^[\-\+]?\d+$/,
                    "alertText": "Not a valid integer"
                },
                "number": {
                    // Number, including positive, negative, and floating decimal. credit: orefalo
                    "regex": /^[\-\+]?((([0-9]{1,3})([,][0-9]{3})*)|([0-9]+))?([\.]([0-9]+))?$/,
                    "alertText": "Invalid floating decimal number"
                },

                //tls warning:homegrown not fielded                 
                "images": {
                    "regex": /^[\w,\s-]+\.[jpg|png|gif]{3}$/,
                    "alertText": "Upload .jpg or .png or .gif format"
                },
                //tls warning:homegrown not fielded                 
                "pdf": {
                    "regex": /^[\w,\s-]+\.[pdf]{3}$/,
                    "alertText": "Upload .pdf format only"
                }                               
            };

        }
    };

    $.validationEngineLanguage.newLang();

})(jQuery);
```

this is my validation scripts but
images fails in IE, no problem with other browser

```
            "images": {
                "regex": /^[\w,\s-]+\.[jpg|png|gif]{3}$/,
                "alertText": "Upload .jpg or .png or .gif format"
            },
```

Comment: `[jpg|png|gif]` should properly be `(jpg|png|gif)`

Comment: Have you try to "alert" the value it has in the image element? please check what appears in the file control to get better idea of it

Answer (score 1):

When you write `[pdf]{3}` you are matching any character among `['p', 'd', 'f']`, repeated three times. Hence, the following extensions will be valid :

```
dfp
dpf
fdp
fpd
pdf
pfd
```

Which is not what you want.

Replace `[pdf]{3}` with just `pdf`.

Similarly, `[jpg|png|gif]{3}` should be replaced with `(jpg|png|gif)`

Comment: Please precise : 1) the value of the string that is not matching against the pattern. 2) your IE version

Answer (score 0):

IE fetch the full path of the file thats why it fails, so just edit regex as follow

/^[\w,\s-/\:]+.(jpg|png|gif)$/